# Convert emoji unicode to hex codepoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji

I am trying to obtain the hex codepoint for emojis.

The code below successfully returns the hex codepoint for emojis without surrogate pairs (e.g. **1f58d** for ️):

```
NSData *data = [@"️" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
uint32_t unicode;
[data getBytes:&unicode length:sizeof(unicode)];
NSLog(@"%x", unicode);
```

However, for emojis like "" which has codepoint **"1f932-1f3ff"**, the method above only returns the first point, **"1f932"**. How can I get the full hex codepoint for emojis with multiple code points please (any code approach is fine)? (Note that certain emojis, like "‍♀️" has up to 5 code points e.g. ‍♀️)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSArray<NSNumber*>*) unicodeCodePoints:(NSString*)unicodeChar
{
    NSMutableArray* codePoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData* data = [unicodeChar dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];

    for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.length / sizeof(UInt32); i++ )
    {
        UInt32* arr = (UInt32*)(data.bytes);

        [codePoints addObject:@(arr[i])];
    }

    return codePoints;
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
for ( NSNumber* num in [self unicodeCodePoints:@"‍♀️"] )
{
    NSLog(@"%0*x", (int)(2*sizeof(UInt32)), (UInt32)[num unsignedIntegerValue]);
}
```

Please note this assumes a single unicode character is represented by the NSString argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `uint32_t` to `uint64_t`.

```
NSData *data = [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
uint64_t unicode;
[data getBytes:&unicode length:sizeof(unicode)];
NSLog(@"%llx", unicode);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only prints the first 2 code points and not those for emojis with more than 2 e.g. ‍♀️ which has 5